# String substition but whole line isn't copied

Tags: windows, batch-file

Hi I have this code to substitute the path and then run iexpress to build an exe.

```
@echo off
set PATH=PATH
set FOLDER=FOLDER
set NEWPATH=%~dp0
set TARGET=%NEWPATH%install_32bitWindows.EXE
echo %TARGET%
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=2*" %%i in (install_32bitWindows.SED) do (
    set str=%%i
    echo %str%
    set str=!str:%PATH%=%TARGET%!
    set str=!str:%FOLDER%=%NEWPATH%!
    echo !str! >> newfile
)
del install_32bitWindows.SED
rename newfile install_32bitWindows.SED
C:/Windows/SysWOW64/iexpress.exe /N %~dp0install_32bitWindows.SED
```

The substitution is done correctly but my problem is that one of the lines a space in it, and everything after the space isn't copied as such:

Originally

```
AppLaunched=c:\windows\system32\cscript.exe "install_32bitWindows.vbs"
```

After script:

```
AppLaunched=c:\windows\system32\cscript.exe
```

Why does the rest of the line get removed? 
Thanks

Comment: Can you give a snippet of your `install_32bitWindows.SED`file.

Comment: With `"tokens=2*"` it is splitting the lines up from the file, but we don't know what is in the file.  To take the entire line use `"delims="` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Because all tokens after the second are concatenated into the implied `%%j` variable, which you are not referring to anywhere.

I 'm not sure what the correct processing would be, but this should point you to the correct direction:

```
>> newfile echo !str! %%j
```

<sub>I have moved the redirection to the beginning of the command so that the space before the `>>` is not spuriously inserted into the output file. Small stuff, but why not be precise?</sub>

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of sample data, this becomes a bit of a guessing game.

Assuming your original ...SED filecontains lines of

```
string=anotherstring
```

and you wish to substitute different for certain fixed strings in that file, then

```
for /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%i in (install_32bitWindows.SED) do (
set str=%%j
```

(Note: `1*` and `%%j`

should work BUT...

You appear to be substituting the newly-created file for the original, but the new file won't start `string=` because you don't output that part. If you want `string=newstring` then

```
echo %%i=!str! >> newfile
```

Finally, it's a really bad idea to use `PATH` as a user-variable in batch. `PATH` contains a semicolon-separated list of directories which batch uses to locate executables if the executable doesn't exist in the current directory. You change it, and batch will get amnesia vey quickly. Same goes for `temp` and `tmp` (point to a temporary directory) and a few other "reserved" names...